# Is there any option to specify what item to choose first when v-slide-group is 'mandatory'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify component `v-slide-group`. There is a prop named 'mandatory' which requires at least one item to be selected. Is there any possibility to specify what element should be selected (the first one is selected by default)

```
<v-slide-group center-active 
               mandatory
               >
    <v-slide-item v-for="item in items" 
                  :key="item.id" 
                  :value="item.value"
    >
      {{ item.name }}
    </v-slide-item>
</v-slide-group>
```

in this case the first item of items is chosen, anyhow i wanted 'N' items to be chosen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try reading documentation and API of components you are trying to use (for example [v-slide-group API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-slide-group/) in which you can see that you can pass `value` prop: `:value="items[n]"` in your case).